# Can't convert a double vector to function using timetk on R version 4.1.0

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

I am having issue when i use the tk_augment_slidify function from timetk library in my R version 4.1.0 - (reprex below) - however,
the same code works fine when i run it on Rmarkdown. Can someone
please help to solve this issue ? - shows me the following error -

> "Error: Can't convert a double vector to function"

Sample data :

```
purchased_at|revenue
2018-06-03  |32735.89
2018-06-10  |38290.07
2018-06-17  |39973.95
2018-06-24  |35621.93
2018-07-01  |28983.72
```

standardize and log transform the data and creating Lags

```
transformed_transdata <- 
transdata %>% 
  mutate(revenue = log(revenue),
         revenue = standardize_vec(revenue))
transformed_transdata %>% 
  bind_rows(
    future_frame(.data = .,
                 .date_var = purchased_at,
                 .length_out = 8)
  ) %>% 
  tk_augment_lags(.data = .,
                  .value = revenue,
                  .lags = 8) %>% 
  tk_augment_slidify(.data = .,
                     .value = revenue_lag8,
                     .f = mean,
                     .period = 8)
```

```
sessionInfo(package = c("tidyverse","timetk","dplyr"))
#> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] tidyverse_1.3.1 timetk_2.6.1    dplyr_1.0.7  
>        knitr_1.33
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have saved some numbers into a variable named mean. For example, in the `tk_augment_slidify` function mean is probably saved as some numeric values, so `tk_augment_slidify` function is getting a numeric value instead of `base::mean` function

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer.